# Split string WITHOUT regex

Tags: r

I'm sure I used to know this, and I'm sure this is covered somewhere but since I can't find any Google/SO hits for this title search there probably should be one..

I want to split a string without using regex, e.g.

```
str = "abcx*defx*ghi"
```

Of course we can use `stringr::str_split` or `strsplit` with argument `'x[*]'`, but how can we just suppress regex entirely?

Comment: The same as `strsplit(str, 'x[*]')`..

Comment: Ah yes.  I'm guessing `str_split` has no method..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument `fixed=TRUE` can be useful in this instance

```
strsplit(str, "x*", fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question also mentions a `stringr::str_split`, a *stringr* way might be of help, too.

You may use `str_split` with `fixed(<YOUR_DELIMITER_STRING_HERE>, ignore_case = FALSE)` or `coll(pattern, ignore_case = FALSE, locale = "en", ...)`. See the [stringr docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf):

> `fixed`: Compare literal bytes in the string. This is very fast, but not usually what you want for non-ASCII character sets.
>   `coll` Compare strings respecting standard collation rules

See the following R demo:

```
> str_split(str, fixed("x*"))
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi"
```

Collations are better illustrated with a letter that can have two representations:

```
> x <- c("Str1\u00e1Str2", "Str3a\u0301Str4")
> str_split(x, fixed("\u00e1"), simplify=TRUE)
     [,1]        [,2]  
[1,] "Str1"      "Str2"
[2,] "Str3áStr4" ""    
> str_split(x, coll("\u00e1"), simplify=TRUE)
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "Str1" "Str2"
[2,] "Str3" "Str4"
```

A [note about `fixed()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html):

> `fixed(x)` only matches the exact sequence of bytes specified by `x`. This is a very limited “pattern”, but the restriction can make matching much faster. Beware using `fixed()` with non-English data. It is problematic because there are often multiple ways of representing the same character. For example, there are two ways to define “á”: either as a single character or as an “a” plus an accent.
>   ...
>   `coll(x)` looks for a match to x using human-language collation rules, and is particularly important if you want to do case insensitive matching. Collation rules differ around the world, so you’ll also need to supply a locale parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the regex inside `fixed()` to stop it being treated as a regex inside `stringr::str_split()`

#### Example

Normally, `stringr::str_split()` will treat the `pattern` as a regular expression, meaning certain characters have special meanings, which can cause errors if those regular expressions are not valid, e.g.:

```r
library(stringr)

str_split("abcdefg[[[klmnop", "[[[")

Error in stri_split_regex(string, pattern, n = n, simplify = simplify,  : 
  Missing closing bracket on a bracket expression. (U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET)
```

But if we simply wrap the `pattern` we are splitting by inside `fixed()`, it treat's it as a string literal, rather than a regular expression:

```
str_split("abcdefg[[[klmnop", fixed("[[["))
[[1]]
[1] "abcdefg" "klmnop"
```